# Java input/output stream for primitive values

Tags: java, stream

I've been reading about java streams and decided to make a simple input class that will read input from the user(keyboard) and return it back.The problem is that i don't know which stream-class to use for simple,primitive values.I made UserInput class using the DataInputStream ,but noticed that i didn't work,because,as i understood,the DataInputStream supports only bufferedStream,and the problem is that i don't know how to flush the input after i read something(There is no flush method).How do i fix this,or could you suggest me another input stream for primitive values(without casting and using of Integer.valueOf() e.t.c methods).Also,i made UserInput with BufferedReader,but i didn't like it,because i had to use methods like:Double/Integer/Short/etc.valueOf()
Here is the code of my class :

```
import java.io.*;
import java.util.InputMismatchException;

public class UserInput {
    static DataInputStream reader;

    public UserInput() {
        reader = new DataInputStream(System.in);
    }

    public int getInt() {
        int result = -1;
        try {
            result = reader.read();
        } catch (IOException ex) {
            ex.printStackTrace();
            System.out.println("Couldn't open buffered.Return -1");
        }
        return result;
    }

    public double getDouble() {
        double result = -1;
        try {
            result = reader.readDouble();
        } catch (IOException ex) {
            ex.printStackTrace();
            System.out.println("Couldn't open buffered.Return -1");
        }
        return result;
    }

    public float getFloat() {
        float result = -1f;
        try {
            result = reader.readFloat();
        } catch (IOException ex) {
            ex.printStackTrace();
            System.out.println("Couldn't open buffered.Return -1");
        }
        return result;
    }

    public long getLong() {
        long result = -1l;
        try {
            result = reader.readLong();
        } catch (IOException ex) {
            ex.printStackTrace();
            System.out.println("Couldn't open buffered.Return -1");
        }
        return result;
    }

    public short getShort() {
        short result = -1;
        try {
            result = reader.readShort();
        } catch (IOException ex) {
            ex.printStackTrace();
            System.out.println("Couldn't open buffered.Return -1");
        }
        return result;
    }

    public String getString() {
        String result = " ";
        try {
            result = reader.readUTF();
        } catch (IOException ex) {
            ex.printStackTrace();
            System.out.println("Couldn't open buffered.Return empty character ");
        }
        return result;
    }

    public char getChar() {
        char result = ' ';
        try {
            result = (char) reader.read();
        } catch (IOException ex) {
            ex.printStackTrace();
            System.out.println("Couldn't open buffered.Return empty character ");
        }
        return result;
    }

    /**
     * Closes the buffer.
     *
     */
    public void close() {
        try {
            if (reader != null) {
                reader.close();
            }
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } finally {
            System.out.println("Inputstream has been closed.");
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I think there's a misunderstanding here - you're treating `System.in` (which is a stream of characters) as a DataInputStream (which is a stream of bytes - something very different)

If your intention is to read various types from `System.in` you could just use operations similar to this:

```
    Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);
    String s = scanner.next();
    System.out.println("Got string: " + s);

    double d = scanner.nextDouble();
    System.out.println("Got double: " + d);
```

So your class could be set up like this:

```
public UserInput() {
    scanner= new Scanner(System.in);
}
```

Otherwise if your intention was to read and write primitives, you'd need to first write those primitives onto a `DataOutputStream`, which is equivalent to a `DataInputStream`. The `System.in` would not be relevant to the exercise in this case.

Comment: So the DataInput/OutputStream are useful only for primitive values written in a file?Are you telling me that i should first write those primitive somewhere(with DataOutputStream),and then read them with DataInputStream?